# axis X dates from the list instead of 1-6

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to use the ceberpunk style chart from this source
https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/matplotlib-cyberpunk-style/
I would like to have on axis X dates from the list instead of 1-6 (2023-01, 2023-02, 2023-03 etc.) How can I do this? I have dates in the 'Data' list.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.style.use("dark_background")

for param in ['text.color', 'axes.labelcolor', 'xtick.color', 'ytick.color']:
    plt.rcParams[param] = '0.9'  # very light grey

for param in ['figure.facecolor', 'axes.facecolor', 'savefig.facecolor']:
    plt.rcParams[param] = '#212946'  # bluish dark grey

colors = [
    '#08F7FE',  # teal/cyan
    '#FE53BB',  # pink
    '#F5D300',  # yellow
    '#00ff41',  # matrix green
]


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, 9, 5, 2, 1, 1],
                   'B': [4, 5, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df.plot(marker='o', color=colors, ax=ax)

# Redraw the data with low alpha and slighty increased linewidth:
n_shades = 10
diff_linewidth = 1.05
alpha_value = 0.3 / n_shades

for n in range(1, n_shades+1):

    df.plot(marker='o',
            linewidth=2+(diff_linewidth*n),
            alpha=alpha_value,
            legend=False,
            ax=ax,
            color=colors)

# Color the areas below the lines:
for column, color in zip(df, colors):
    ax.fill_between(x=df.index,
                    y1=df[column].values,
                    y2=[0] * len(df),
                    color=color,
                    alpha=0.1)

ax.grid(color='#2A3459')

ax.set_xlim([ax.get_xlim()[0] - 0.2, ax.get_xlim()[1] + 0.2])  # to not have the markers cut off
ax.set_ylim(0)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `plt.xticks`

```
plt.xticks(range(len(data)), data)
```

Assuming your `data` list is

```
['2023-01', '2023-02', '2023-03', '2023-04', '2023-05', '2023-06', '2023-07']
```

[image]